# CSS in a project Angular

Tags: angular

I have a folder named `about` with a file `about.component.css` 
I would like the background-color to be in `aqua` only for the page `about.component.html`.

If I do in the file `about.component.css` this:

```
body {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

Nothing is displayed...
This file in CSS is on this path:
`C:\dev\demo\src\app\home\home.component.css`

I think that I have to call the file `home.component.css` somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the [documentation on Angular component styles](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each component doesn't have it's own `<body>` tag. You'd have to wrap the entire component with an explicit tag to apply styles to it.

Eg.

**app.component.html**

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
```

**hello.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <div class="custom-bg">
      <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .custom-bg {
        background-color: aqua;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jk6fpa?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: I guess `:host` can also work is there any pros vs cons ?

Comment: Ideally you would use `:host`. The div doesn't serve any other purpose in this instance

Answer (score 2):

```
:host {
 background-color: aqua;
}
```